# Add custom user controls from a referenced library to the toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

In WinForms projects (ie. VS solutions) using .NET4.0 I want to add custom controls to the toolbox which are contained in a library. The library DLLs are installed via NuGet. Individual solutions may use different versions of that library and thus may use different versions of the controls.

In the Visual Studio settings I see that *Automatically Populate Toolbox* is set to **True** for the Windows Forms Designer. However, the controls are not loaded. I can only add them by drag & dropping the DLL onto the toolbox or use the context menu "Choose Items...".

Then the controls show up, but the sourced DLL for the controls is not specific to a solution. It's the same for every Visual Studio solution leading to the problem that different solutions **cannot** use different versions of the controls.

Checks:

- The controls implement `IComponent`
- The controls do not have `ToolboxItemAttribute` or `DesignTimeVisibleAttribute` set to `false`

How can I accomplish that the projects are using their referenced version of the custom controls?

Answer (score 0):

Historically, VS controls are not per project; that would imply a reference on your .csproj file for example, stating any custom control that you want to see in the tookbox.